# Terraform Azure configuration - tfvars complex type variable

Tags: azure, variables, configuration, terraform

I'd like to configure tfvars json file for Azure logic app, especially I mean parameters and workflow_parameters which are complex type.

When I tried to set variable type as "any" (for objects) I got an error: `Inappropriate value for attribute "workflow_parameters": incorrect map element type: string required.`

When set type as "string": `map of any single type required`
or eventually: `all map elements must have the same type`, when I tried to add `"type":"map(string)"`.

What type should that element have and how to configure it properly?

Here's my current config for tfvars:

```
{
  "location": "xyz",
  "resource_group_name": "xyz",
  "logic_app_name": "xyz",
  "workflow_schema": "https://xyz.json#",
  "workflow_version": "1.0.0.0",
  "state": "true",
  "parameters": {
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "azureblob_hdl_1": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/123/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/xyz/managedApis/azureblob",
          "connectionId": "/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob_hdl_1",
          "connectionName": "azureblob_hdl_1"
        },
        "sftpssh_gxs_1": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/123/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/xyz/managedApis/sftp",
          "connectionId": "/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sftpssh_gxs_1",
          "connectionName": "sftpssh_gxs_1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "workflow_parameters": {
    "$connections": {
      "defaultValue": {},
      "type": "Object"
    }
  }
}
```

and for variables.tf:

```
{
(...)
  "variable": {
    "parameters": {
      "type": "any"
    }
  },
  "variable": {
    "workflow_parameters": {
      "type": "any"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the terraform [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#type-constraints):

> The type argument in a variable block allows you to restrict the type of value that will be accepted as the value for a variable. **If no type constraint is set then a value of any type is accepted**.

Have you tried to not set it at all?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but then in the terraform plan there is a change with deletion of these parameters content (resource already exists on Azure and has that configuration)